# Map vs Map<K,V>

Tags: java, dictionary

I'd like to find out why `UnmodifiableMap.decorate(Map map)` from Apache Commons operates on `Map` and returns `Map` instead of `Map<K,V>`. What's the difference between these two approaches?

Comment: Related, [`java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap(java.util.Map)) is type-parameterized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the Apache Commons collections predate generics, and haven't been updated for them.

You may wish to look at [this unofficial version](http://larvalabs.com/collections/) which is a port of Apache Commons Collections to generics, or at [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) for an alternative library with support for other collections. (There are others, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because of some sort of backward compatibility. The `Map<K,V>` can be used just in Java 5 and above.

Answer (score 1):

Jon is probably right.

You may be able to cast to Map when it's retruned.

```
Map<K,V> myMap = (Map<K,V>)UnmodifiableMap.decorate(Map map);
```